# Adding css and javascript to Yii's CHtml and other attributes

Tags: javascript, css, forms, yii

how do you covert this html code into the yii CHtml?

```
<form aciton='site/qrcode' method='POST'>
<input type='text' value='Generate Code here..' name='generate' id='gen' onclick='checkval()' class='ext'>
<input type='submit' value='Generate' id='submit'>
</form>
```

can anyone please help? My main aim of this is to knkow how to put a class and Onclick event in a textbox or button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the third parameter of the textField method (htmlOptions array), like this:

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>

    <?php echo CHtml::textField('generate','Generate Code here...', array('id'=>'gen', 'onclick'=>'checkval()', 'class'=>'ext')) ?>

    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Generate', array('id'=>'submit')); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

(I left all the opening and closing tags for other html to be interspersed.)

Comment: thank you so much... this will help me a lot. but one more thing.... how do you specify the "aciton='site/qrcode' method='POST'" in the CHtml::beginForm() widget?

Comment: @ChUck_PrOg http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#beginForm-detail, you should be able to figure out how to specify action and method, from that link.